# An object, two select dropdowns, ng-options and value binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I'm trying to do the following:

- When the user select a family, its **parent's name is auto-selected** in the second dropdown
- When the controller set the object (in case of a model update form for example), the two dropdowns should reflect this object: **family and parent should be auto-selected**.

[See this example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVdeXZ?editors=101)

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.families = [
        { name: "My first family", parent: "Parent #1" },
        { name: "My second family", parent: "Parent #2" },
        { name: "My third family", parent: "Parent #1" }
    ];

    $scope.importNew = function() {
        $scope.model = { name: "My third family", parent: "Parent #1" };
        $scope.message = "Problem: ^ the family name isn't bind, only the parent!";
    }

    $scope.importRef = function() {
        $scope.model = $scope.families[2];
        $scope.message = "It works!";
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>ng-options model binding</h1>
    <select ng-options="fam.name group by fam.parent for fam in families"
            ng-model="model">
        <option disabled value="">— Choose —</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-options="fam.parent as fam.parent for fam in families"
            ng-model="model.parent">
        <option disabled value="">— Choose —</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="importNew()">Import a family (new family object)</button>
    <button ng-click="importRef()">Import a family (referenced family object)</button>
    <p><small>{{ message }}</small></p>

    <p>
        <strong>$scope.model :</strong>
        <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>$scope.families :</strong>
        <pre>{{ families | json }}</pre>
    </p>
</div>
```

**Problem**: when setting a new family model, the binding isn't effective.

Answer (score 0):

For the auto-select to work, **the object must be part of the array from which the select dropdowns are feed**.

```js
// Auto-select won't work: this is a new object, even if it is equal to an existing object in the list
$scope.model = { name: "My third family", parent: "Parent #1" }

// Auto-select will work: the object is directly one of the dropdowns' list
$scope.model = $scope.families[2]
```